# Cannot install mvvmcross download cache pluguin with xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross, mvxlistview

Mvvmcross version 4.4.0

xamarin forms need `Xamanarin.android.support.v4/v7.x` version 23.0.0
Download Cachè plugin need `Xamarin.android.support.compat` version 24.2.1

My app is using xamarin forms so i cant remove it, but i also need to use MvxListView to show an image from url with `local:MvxBind="ImageUrl myimage"`
so i need download cache plugin, but i cant install it.

Is there any other IMvxImageHelper to use instead of MvvmCross-DownloadCache plugin ? or any other solution ?

*IMPORTANT NOTE-> No code in the Android View.

Comment: Xamarin.Forms depends on old Xamarin.Android.Support packages. So these are incompatible, unfortunately.

Comment: I know but how to give a round ?  i need to load an Image from string url into imageView...

Comment: FFImageLoading as @Joehl suggests in his answer is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the Xamarin.Forms Plugin [FFImageLoading - Fast & Furious Image Loading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading). It works like a charm and the image loading is much faster than without this plugin. So just take a look at it.

You can find detailed documentation on [this github wiki](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki).

Here's a short Xaml example how to use it:

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
            WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300"
            DownsampleToViewSize="true"
            Source = "http://loremflickr.com/600/600/nature?filename=simple.jpg">
</ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, it's not working yet but I think you gave me the way !, I'll accept your answer as fast as I make it work !

Comment: Ok. Or just ask me, maybe I can help you out

Comment: Well i have a property in viewmodel wich is an image url i just need to bind it in am imageview without using the android view so i cant use mvx.mvxlistview as i said but with ffimageloading there has to be a way, the axml code you provided me is not working for what i need but there are other image tags from ffimageloading that can give me the solution , now im out but i'll be back in 2 or 3 hours thank you for your efforts, and dont worry i just need a little more time ! :)

Comment: You can use the xaml-code I provided in a Xamarin.Forms page (in your PCL/Shared project). This should work with a binding to your viewmodel. Have fun and feel free to ask again, if you need further help

Comment: These are the following tags that the xml import recognizes. the atributes of the documentation are not working i can set android:layout_width and height but i cant bind the Url '<FFImageLoading.Forms.Droid.CachedImageRenderer />
  <FFImageLoading.Forms.Droid.CachedImageView />
  <ffimageloading.views.ImageViewAsync />
  <FFImageLoading.Views.ManagedImageView />
  <ffimageloading.cross.MvxImageLoadingView />'

Comment: We shouldn't discuss this in the comment-section of StackOverflow. Please update/extend your question or ask a new one with detailed informations. Thanks