# FFimageLoading NugetPackage for Xamarin MVVMCross 4.4.0

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross, ffimageloading

As stated in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40846151/cannot-install-mvvmcross-download-cache-pluguin-with-xamarin-forms) I need to load an image from Url using `Xamarin.Forms` with `MVVMCross 4.4.0`.

I was directed to use the [FFimageLoading package](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki) in that question but it is not working, after searching I found that the FFimageLoading library has this axml tag:

```
<ffimageloading.cross.MvxImageLoadingView/>
```

I have a `MvxListView` and in each ListItem I need to show an image from Url, but there's no way as `Xamarin.forms` and `Mvx.MvximageView` ImageUrl are using diferent versions of the same dependency.

I have a Model class with `String imgUrl`, a viewModel with a `observableCollection<myclass> items` wich has the imgUrl ( `items.imgUrl` ) but when I try to bind in axml it is not working.

```
<ffimageloading.cross.MvxImageLoadingView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
            local:MvxBind="Source imgUrl" />
```

Comment: Maybe you can directly take the code, it's not much: https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/blob/master/source/FFImageLoading.Cross/MvxImageLoadingView.cs then propose a PR if there is a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use xamarin.forms with mvvmcross4.4.0 at 02/12/2016.

xamarin forms has dependencies to old versions off android.support.appcompat.v4/v7 so i cant use the Mvx.MvxImageView to show images from Url, and implementing a navigation menu is so hard.

this is my conclusion about this issue i created. I'm going to remove xamarin forms of my solution.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: You are using `Xamarin.Forms` but you are also talking about a axml-view in your android project. I know, sometimes there is no other way, but try to keep your UI together in your shared/pcl project (because it's one of the main cases of using `Xamarin.Forms`).

I never worked with the MvvmCross view of the plugin (`MvxImageLoadingView`), but I think you should use a an `UriImageSource` as type of your `imgUrl` property instead of just a string (looking at [this page in the documentation](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API#source)).

Comment: i get  'Xamarin.Forms.UriImageSource' cannot be converted to type 'System.Nullable`1[FFImageLoading.Work.ImageSource]'. so i cast it to FFImageLoading.Work.ImageSource but .... System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.